# Compare/access object's properties dynamically with string reference

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, gettype

I have a simple class:

```
class Event {
     public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a List of this class:

```
var list = new List<Event>();
        list.Add(new Event { Source="Me" });
        list.Add(new Event { Source="You" });
```

Now I want to get one Event in the list with the "Source" property set to "Me".

BUT I don't want to access this property like this list[0].Source like this:

```
list.Where(o => o.Source == "Me").Single()
```

I know that my object has the "Source" property. but I need to pass a string to get this property and compare it. Something like this:

```
list.Where(o => o.GetType().GetProperty("Source").GetType() == "Me").Single()
```

Apparently, this doesn't work. Basicaly I need to be able to write a comparison like `o.Source == "ME"` without referencing the property directly.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You could try Microsoft's Dynamic LINQ library, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx after downloading go to LinqSamples/DynamicQuery in the zip file here's a nice blog post about it https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: why `.GetType() == "Me"`? Should you get the value and compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the `GetValue` method instead

```
list.Where(o => o.GetType().GetProperty("Source").GetValue(o, null) == "Me").Single()
```